# Why isn't this data getting sent into Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux and I think I'm starting to understand how it all works, but I'm having initial problems getting data into the Store.

I believe I'm close, but there's just something that I'm not getting. Any help is appreciated!

The reason I need this to work is because I have other components that will work with the same data, so I figured it's best to keep the data in the Redux Store. If there are other ways to solve this, please enlighten me.

Action:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

export const LOAD_DATA     = "LOAD_DATA";

function getApiUrl() {
return `${window.appDefaultState.url.baseUrl}/api`;
}

export function loadStoresData() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_DATA,
      stores: data
    });
fetch(
  getApiUrl(),
  {
    method: "post",
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      form_key: window.appDefaultState.formKey,
      "cms/stores": 1
    })
  }
)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  console.log("fetched data in actions")
  let data = json["cms/stores"];
  console.log(data);
  dispatch({
    type: LOAD_DATA,
    stores: data
  });
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
});
}
}

function getSuccess(data) {
  console.log("getSuccess worked")
  return (
    type: LOAD_DATA,
    stores: data
  )
}
```

Reducer:

```
import {
  LOAD_DATA
} from "actions/storelist.js";

function initialState() {
  return Object.assign({}, {
    stores: {},
  }, window.appDefaultState.storeList);
}

export default function storeList(state, action) {
  if (!state) {
    state = initialState();
}

switch (action.type) {
  case LOAD_DATA:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      stores: action.data
  });
  break;
}

return state;
}
```

Component (relevant parts):

```
import { connect }                  from "react-redux";
import { loadStoresData }           from "actions/storelist.js";

const actions = {
  loadStoresData
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return Object.assign({
    stores: state.stores
}, ownProps);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(StorePage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dispatch `data` in `stores` field, so it should be

```
switch (action.type) {
  case LOAD_DATA:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      stores: action.stores
    });
}
```

Replace `action.data` with `action.stores`